# drf-yasg Swagger documentation does not recognize authorized users

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, authorization, swagger-ui, drf-yasg

I've set up [DRF-YASG](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html#) documentation for my Django project, but the endpoints that require authentication show no parameters (fields to fill) even when logged as an authorized user.

[swagger ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NawJ.png)

In fact, none of my endpoints show their respective parameter fields in the UI.

Here are my REST_FRAMEWORK settings in `settings.py` :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY": "errors",
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES":(
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication"
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSON_CLASSES":(
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"
    )
}
```

and `urls.py:`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from EmployeeApp import views

from rest_framework import permissions
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="Snippets API",
        default_version='v1',
        description="Test description",
        terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@snippets.local"),
        license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny],
)

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^swagger(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0),
            name='schema-json'),
    path('', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    re_path(r'^redoc/$', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.api_home),
    path('api/', include('EmployeeApp.urls')),
    path('api/auth/', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

I am using standard token authentication and here are my views.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from .serializers import SignUpSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema


class SignUpView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = SignUpSerializer

    def post(self, request: Request):
        data = request.data

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

            response = {
                "message": "User Created Successfully",
                "data": serializer.data
            }

            return Response(data=response, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class LoginView(APIView):

    @swagger_auto_schema(request_body=UserSerializer)
    def post(self, request: Request):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user:
            response = {
                "message": "Login Successful",
                "token": user.auth_token.key
            }
            return Response(data=response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(data={"message": "Invalid username or password"},
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    def get(self, request: Request):
        content = {
            "user": str(request.user),
            "auth": str(request.auth)
        }

        return Response(data=content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In Postman everything works as expected, but in the Swagger documentation the authenticated user is not being recognized and the parameter fields on endpoints are missing.

Not sure if these two issues are connected, but I would apprechiate any type of helpful input on this!

1. I have tested the endpoints with direct Postman requests and everything works as expected.

[image]
[image]

Here is the endpoint to Create(POST) a company as a logged User:

```
class CompanyCreate(APIView):

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_summary="Create a company",
        operation_description="This allows logged-in user to create a company"
    )
    def post(self, request):
        company_name_exists = Companies.objects.filter(company_name=request.data['company_name']).exists()
        if company_name_exists:
            raise ValidationError("Company with the same name already exists")

        data = {**request.data, 'user_id': request.auth.user_id}

        serializer = CompanySerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and it's serializer:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Companies
        fields = ('user_id', 'company_name', 'company_description', 'company_logo')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        company, is_created = Companies.objects.get_or_create(
                                        company_name=validated_data['company_name'],
                                        company_description=validated_data['company_description'],
                                        company_logo=validated_data['company_logo'],
                                        user_id=validated_data['user_id'],
                                        )
        return company
```

2. I've attached `

```
@swagger_auto_schema(request_body=UserSerializer)
```

`
to my login endpoint and it gives me a filed to put the request body data in a JSON format.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmker.png)

that works, but it still does not show the Swagger UI parameter fields and the auth does not persist when I try to test endpoints that require it.

Comment: can you show your postman screenshot? can you show your /companies endpoint method?

Comment: Hello, I've edited in my post above this additional info.